# impala sql transpose multiple columns to rows

Tags: sql, nosql, impala

I'd like to transpose my columns to rows in impala using SQL.
Below is what I'm working with and the desired output underneath. The data is few million records and around a hundred columns but the 2 records are for for illustration purposes only. Will processing such a large dataset be an issue? Any help is appreciated!

```
As is:  
ID   x1   x2   x3   x4    x5  
1    2    4     6    8    10  
2    1    3     5    7     9
```

Desired output:

```
ID     VARIABLE     VALUE  
1         X1        2  
1         X2        4  
1         X3        6  
1         X4        8  
1         X5       10  
2         X1        1  
2         X2        3
2         X3        5
2         X4        7
2         X5        9
```

Thanks

Comment: if you could post the same data and output instead of image that would be helpful for the solution

Answer (score 0):

Well, you didn't mention your dbms (oracle?, mysql?, sqlserver?) but check out pivot and unpivot construction as starting point. Here an example if you are on Oracle:

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=conversion-of-columns-into-rows

Comment: Apologies, I'm using NoSql (Apache Hive) which doesn't have UNPIVOT option, does this help?